# Select data from multiple tables using SQL

Tags: sql

I have three tables as follows,

```
student table
{sid, sname}
e.g.
1 Billy
2 Bob
3 David


subject table
{subid, subname}

 e.g.
      15 Maths
      16 Science
      62 Art

grades table
{sid, subid, marks, grades}

e.g.
      1 15 69 B
      1 16 56 C
      1 62 23 W
      2 15 45 C
      2 16 99 A
      2 62 80 A
      3 15 20 W
      3 16 40 S
      3 62 71 B
```

I want to retrieve data as follows,

```
Billy Maths 69 B Science 56 C Art 23 W
Bob   Maths 45 C Science 99 A Art 80 A 
David Maths 20 W Science 40 S Art 71 B
```

Is this possible in SQL?  If so, how? Please help.

Comment: The last C of the first row of your expected result seems to be incorrect and should be a W? You should please tag your DBMS because a correct query for this question will very likely depend on it.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Yes. It's a W. Is this possible? I tried so many ways. But I couldn't do it.

Comment: As said, I think you need to tag your DBMS (Oracle, Postgres, sth else), please.

Comment: In SQL you select before-known columns. In your case there are three columns for the grades for Maths, Science, and Art. If a subject gets added to the subject table, that query will still only select the grades for Maths, Science, and Art. If however, you just want one column for a string containing the grades, like 'Maths 69 B Science 56 C Art 23 W', then this query can consider all subjects, because the query does not have to know which subjects to show beforehand.

Comment: It was tagged as mySQL :( and now no dbms tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you would need to use concatting functions and join. Your database of choice might have different functions to GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT, but it should work in MariaDB and MySQL

Here is an example of how to do this.

```sql
SELECT student.sname, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(subject.subname, ' ', grades.marks, ' ', grades.grades) SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM student
JOIN grades ON grades.sid = student.sid
JOIN subject ON subject.subid = grades.subid
GROUP BY student.sid
```

Here is an example of it running https://dbfiddle.uk/RtiHsEmQ

Comment: @JonasMetzler Misread the question, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Oh I got that OP wanted them as separate columns.

Comment: Thanks for correcting, I think this query is good now or should at least be a sufficient help. I refused to make a proposal without knowing the DBMS, but as Cetin mentioned in the comments, MYSQL seems to have been taged before. And even if not, the OP should be able to google the correct function for their DMBS ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is it doable, yes it is. Should you do it in the style you showed, probably not. That is known as cross tab or pivoting.
For your very *specific case* here is an ugly way of doing that:

```
select st.sname, 
       max(case when sb.subid = 15 then sb.subname end) as 'S1',
       max(case when sb.subid = 15 then g.Marks end) as 'M1',
       max(case when sb.subid = 15 then g.grades end) as 'G1',
       max(case when sb.subid = 16 then sb.subname end) as 'S2',
       max(case when sb.subid = 16 then g.Marks end) as 'M2',
       max(case when sb.subid = 16 then g.grades end) as 'G2',
       max(case when sb.subid = 62 then sb.subname end) as 'S3',
       max(case when sb.subid = 62 then g.Marks end) as 'M3',
       max(case when sb.subid = 62 then g.grades end) as 'G3'
  from grades g 
  inner join student st on st.sid = g.sid
  inner join subject sb on sb.subid = g.subid
  group by st.sid, st.sname
  order by st.sname;
```

I don't know what cross tab libraries may exist in mySQL to make it easier. Say in postgreSQL, you might use tablefunc.

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/U3ePAiSi)

EDIT: Now that you removed the DBMS tag, it might be postgereSQL, then you could JSON functions to build that up even in case of unknown subjects beforehand (or using dynamic SQL is an option).